# Any native Capacitor Integration (Plug-in) for live streaming (Audio and Video) to Ionic (5-Angular) Apps

Tags: ionic-framework, video-streaming, broadcast, capacitor

colleagues, due to the pandemic, virtualization was ahead of us, and now many companies are looking to work online and do live broadcasts within their applications.

So I am looking for, and asking you if you know or have any experience with live audio and video transmission system that integrates natively with Ionic (Preferably version 5, and Angular) and Capacitor, In order to Ionic developers can make apps with that feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate with Zoom, We did that and it works decently well.

Now that we need better performance we are switching to Flutter, but to answer you in short, you can do it easliy with Zoom.

Here's a link to help you out: https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/sdk/native-sdks/ionic/getting-started/install